# Win 10 IIS User Identity in sub process

Tags: python, c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have a C# ASP.NET Backend for a Website that is hosted on a Windows 10 Machine with IIS.
It is working, and I can communicate with the Backend via REST.
The C# ASP.NET calls a Python script as one of its REST calls.
Due to some User restrictions, the Python script needs to be executed as a Domain user to have access rights to some internal resources.
I configured the Application Pool Identity (Advanced Settings) in IIS with the custom domain account the Python script should be started with.
I also tried setting the "Managed Pipeline Mode" to "Classic" after some research, which also didn't fix my problem.
During the runtime of the C# Backend i can confirm it uses the configured user with:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

I start the python script using the Process class:

```
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WorkingDirectory = info.WorkingDirectory,
                FileName = "python.exe",
                Arguments = info.GenerateArguments(),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                // UserName = userName,
            };

            using (Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = start,
            })
            {
                // manual process kill since cancelationtoken is not doing that here
                ct.Register(() => process.Kill(true));

                Log.Information($"Starting Process: {start.FileName} with args: {start.Arguments}");

                process.Start();
```

I already tuned the startup arguments in many ways, but for some reason the python script called by this Process is started with a different user. This user is local and called "[PcName]$".

I don't want to manually set the username and password in clear text into the application for security. There has to be a way that the python subprocess can just inherit the user rights...
Or is there another way to start the python with given arguments so that I can inherit the user? I really don't care if it's the Process class or some other starting option.

Comment: Print out the process ID and see if the `process` in your code actually matches the `python.exe` you see from Windows Task Manager or Process Explorer.